# Enclosing function calls in go routines

Tags: clojure, core.async

I am trying to wrap a go routine inside a function (as in Method 1 below). Method 2 works perfectly fine, but Method 1 doesn't. The only difference is that in Method 1, I am passing a channel as a parameter to a function and the put is inside the function. What are the exact rules concerning go routines and functions?

```
(defn doit [ch i]
  (print "g\n")
  (async/>! ch i)
  (print "f\n"))
```

;Method 1

```
(let [c1 (async/chan)]
  (async/go (while true
      (let [[v ch] (async/alts! [c1])]
         (println "Read" v "from" ch))))
  (dotimes [i 10]
     (async/go (doit c1 i))))
```

;Method 2

```
(let [ch (async/chan)]
   (async/go (while true       
      (let [[v ch] (async/alts! [ch])]
          (println "Read" v "from" ch))))
   (dotimes [i 10]
     (async/go
       (print "g\n")
       (async/>! ch i)
       (print "f\n"))))
```

I also noticed that if I remove the go in Method 1 and move it to the do it function as shown below, the function prints "g" but not "f" but otherwise works fine. Why?

```
(defn doit [ch i]
  (async/go
   (print "g\n")
   (async/>! ch i)
   (print "f\n")))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`>!` and `<!` are not really functions that get called (see [here](https://github.com/clojure/core.async/blob/ca148ebf812576b9eaa777adac6927ac22349a62/src/main/clojure/cljs/core/async.cljs#L58) and [here](https://github.com/clojure/core.async/blob/ca148ebf812576b9eaa777adac6927ac22349a62/src/main/clojure/cljs/core/async.cljs#L83)). The `go` macro identifies these two symbols and auto-magically generates code according to the semantics of those two operators. So this macro has no way of knowing that a function uses the `>!` or `<!` operator internally, since all it gets is the forms that calls that function.

**Method 1** is actually throwing an exception on each call to `doit` since the actual code for `>!` and `<!` is just an assertion that always fails. Evaluating the code for this method in a REPLy session started with `lein repl` shows the exception `Exception in thread "async-dispatch-46" java.lang.AssertionError: Assert failed: >! used not in (go ...) block` a bunch of times (10 to be exact). If you are using a REPL through an nREPL client you might not be seeing this because the exception is thrown asynchronously in the server and the client is not taking this into account.

Additionally instead of using `(print "something\n")` you could just use `(println "something")`, not really related to your question but thought I mentioned this.

Comment: Ok, thanks. That still doesn't explain why the "f" string is not printed when I move go macro to the doit function.

Comment: @Tim When evaluating the `doit` function with the `go` block, in the same REPL session (started with `lein repl`) I'm seeing the `f`s printed interleaving with the string `Read v from  #<ManyToManyChannel ...>`. The reason why you are not seeing it printed might be the same as the reason why you weren't seeing the exception (i.e. the output happens asynchronously and your nREPL client doesn't handle that well).